# What is the purpose of the App Store provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, ad-hoc-distribution

I know the obvious answer : it's for distributing apps on the app store. But I have an app approved for release on iTunes Connect with no App Store profile. I just have an Ad Hoc distribution profile installed. What purpose does an App Store distribution profile serve ? I submit my apps through the Test flight program, is it not a problem as long as the build was verified and approved ? I don't want to risk the app somehow not working once it's on the app store.

Comment: I don't have an answer because I've never figured one out: Apple resigns your binary for distribution, and you've verified your identity for submission by username/password. So I look forward to an answer as to why user-side signing for the App Store is required.

Answer (score 2):

To understand what is the purpose of App store provisioning profile we need to check the difference between them first.

**Ad-Hoc Distribution :**

- By using this, App can be installed on 100 devices designated by the developer on his provisioning portal. We can prepare build using this only for beta testing or demos.

**App-store Distribution :**

- By using this we can prepare build of the App to deploy to App store submission.

**Your case:**

- As you mentioned that you submitted app with using ad-hoc distribution profile & its approved & ready for sale now.
- Try to install that live app on the device, for which UDID is not added to Ad-hoc distribution profile. It will not allow to install.
- That is the only difference.

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

If your app made it this far and was approved for release, you're fine. In all probability if you go to the Member Center you'll find that an app store distribution profile was generated for you.

Answer (score 1):

This should be helpful:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

Code signing is used in combination with your App ID, provisioning profile, and entitlements to ensure that:

Your app is built and signed by you or a trusted team member.

Apps signed by you or your team run only on designated development devices.

Apps run only on the test devices you specify.

Your app isn’t using app services you didn’t add to your app.

Only you can upload builds of your app to iTunes Connect.

If you choose to distribute outside of the store (Mac only), the app can’t be modified and distributed by someone else.